# How to add a custom shipping method programmatically?

Tags: shopify, shipping-method

I'm trying to develop a Shopify app extension currently which will just:

- Add a custom shipping method for a store
- If an order is placed with this shipping method, notify me by email

Does anyone know which APIs I need to take a look at in order to do this? I have tried the CarrierService API, but I don't see the CarrierService when checking out a product.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the following API's:

1. Shopify Admin API (Create the custom shipping method)
2. Script Tag API (Custom JS into the store checkout)
3. Webhooks (listen for order/create event)
4. Use sendgrid or manual SMTP for the emails

Create a custom app using the Shopify Admin API, implement custom shipping, then make a webhook for the order event, send email.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I appreciate this. Could you expand on point (1) a bit? I don’t see which admin API lets you create a custom shipping method so that will be helpful.

Comment: @Illian FulfillmentService API

Please tick my answer if it has worked for you.